# How to convert vinyl to memtx in tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

I've created a table in `vinyl` engine (disk), how can I convert it to `memtx` engine (ram)?

I have some small table that would be better if it converted to `memtx` for something like this:

```
WITH x AS ( -- big table that wont fit in memory 
  SELECT cat_id, click_count FROM bla WHERE user_id = ?
), mx AS (
  SELECT MAX(click_count) max_click FROM x
)
SELECT IFNULL(x.click_count,0)/IFNULL((SELECT max_click FROM mx),1) 
  , listings.*
FROM listings -- a small table less than 100k records which better in memory
  LEFT JOIN x 
    ON listings.cat_id = x.cat_id
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

but currently `listings` table is a `vinyl` table, how to convert it in `memtx`?
tried to find in [documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.6/reference/reference_lua/box_schema/#box-schema-space-create), there's no other method other than `create` in `box.space` related to engine.

If there's a way to rename old table, create a new space with proper engine, insert from old table, then drop the old table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do dump/restore with tarantool/dump

Or  you may walk the whole space and copy it row by row

Or create a replica with changed engine

Comment: 'Or create a replica with changed engine'. I suspect it is not obvious and some intruction is necessary. Are you about setting a trigger on _space?

Comment: Looks like last option is partially described here
https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_ctl/on_schema_init/